# Hide Menu on scroll down (but only after 50px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-experience

This script makes it so when you scroll down in a browser the navigation bar disappears/hides behind the header. I was wondering if it was possible if instead it hid as soon as you scrolled down, hiding it after a user scrolls down a certain number of pixels (say 50px) to avoid touchy nav hiding on slightest scroll.

Thanks in advance for any direction.

// Nav scroll test

```
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('#belowhead');

$window.on('scroll', function(){

  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: Is anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can put this inside your "window.on('scroll')" function:

```
if(scrollTop > 50) {

  nav.addClass('hidden');

} else {

  nav.removeClass('hidden');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**2019 Update / Adjustment**

The following could be useful for anyone else wishing to develop a header that disappears when you scroll down. I just finished making the following for a website I'm creating that required the top header to disappear when the user started scrolling, but then reappear when they start scrolling up; continuously applying this logic if you were to constantly keep scrolling up and down on the website.

For starters, a class is added to my `header` tag called `nav-scrolled` when the user scrolls past a certain point - 50px in this case. This new class can then be styled to change the `background-color`, add a `box-shadow` etc...

```
$(function() {
    var header = $(".nav-container");

    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 50) {
            header.addClass("nav-scrolled");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("nav-scrolled");
        }
    })
});
```

However, this only solved the problem of not being able to edit the headers styles if the user is scrolling from the top of the page - not anywhere on the site - the following fixes this.

```
  var userScroll;
  var scrollTop = 0;
  var delta = 5;
  var navHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

  $(window).scroll(function(event){
      userScroll = true;
  });

  setInterval(function() {
      if (userScroll) {
          hasScrolled();
          userScroll = false;
      }
  }, 250);
```

The next step for me was to sequentially add and remove classes `show-nav` and `hide-nav` that had been styled to display and hide the navigation menu. The following checks whether the user has scrolled (up or down) to a value higher than my `delta` variable. If the user is beginning to scroll up on the website, the class `show-nav` is added and the header transitions in from the top of the page. If the user is scrolling down the page the class `hide-nav` is added, and the header is hidden.

```
function hasScrolled() {
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();
      // Ensures a higher scroll than $delta
      if(Math.abs(scrollTop - st) <= delta)
          return;
      // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
      // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
      if (st > scrollTop && st > navHeight){
          // Scroll Down
          $('header').removeClass('show-nav').addClass('hide-nav');
          $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('open');
          $('.menu-left').removeClass('collapse');
      } else {
          // Scroll Up
          if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
              $('header').removeClass('hide-nav').addClass('show-nav');
          }
      }
      scrollTop = st;
  }
```